# How to insert a text into a div node using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to put a text into div () by using selenium. I use python and insert javascript into my code. Here is my code :

```
js="document.getElementsByClassName(\"inputPanel\")[0].innerText=\"hello!\";"
```

But It remind me there is a mistake:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined
```

how can I solve this problem? If you can help, I would appreciate it  !!

Comment: Add your code here, not an image of it.

Comment: Just remove the dot "." before `.inputPanel`

Comment: Please paste the code here, in a formatted way. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a *character sequence* into a `<div>` node you can use the following solution:

```
my_desired_text = "lzylzylzy"
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('inputPanel')[0].innerHTML="+ my_desired_text)
```

Comment: but i still get this warning @DebanjanB

Comment: it said my desired text is not defined,i wonder if you can help me further.thank you@DebanjanB

Comment: @Izy `my_desired_text` is a variable which you can assign with any text. I have updated my answer. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: thank you for your further help ! yeah ,i know what you mean,i replaced my_desired_text with string before.and also i used your answer to replace my code.But it still warn me like this:selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: lzylzylzy is not defined . i thought maybe it is not a  grammar mistake.@DebanjanB

Comment: i only know that we usually use <input> to upload string.but this time i find that <div> is editable.i want to upload a string into it .the webpage source code is like this:     <div contenteditable="true" class="inputPanel" style="height: 83px; outline: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden auto; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; width: 100%; resize: none;"></div>. would you please give me some suggestion to solve this problem？ @DebanjanB

Comment: @Izy Addressing the error `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: lzylzylzy is not defined` and sending _character sequence_ to a `contenteditable="true"` element is altogether a different question. As the error `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined` is resolved now can you accept the answer and raise a new question as per your new requirement please?

Answer (score 1):

Remove **.** placed before inputPanel and also there is no end tag of **[**

Expected Code will be

`document.getElementsByClassName(\"inputPanel\")[0].innerText=\"hello!\";"`